# Configure native vi to emit spaces instead of tabs and not convert autoindent spaces to tabs?

Tags: editor, vi

I would like to use spaces instead of tabs when editing Perl scripts with the native vi found on Solaris systems.

I know this can be done with the vim clone, but I don't have access to install vim on these systems as they are vendor locked.

Firstly, is there a way to configure vi to emit spaces when I press TAB?

And secondly, I am also using the auto-indent feature of vi:

```
:set ai
```

The problem is, when I manually enter spaces for indenting vi converts groups of 8 spaces into tabs automatically when it does auto-indenting. I guess if I can find a way to turn this functionality off it will be a start.

Comment: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Converting_tabs_to_spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an outside-the-box option, could you export the Solaris filesystem using NFS and edit the files you need on another system with a more capable editor?

Comment: I could, and that is a good suggestion. I would like to avoid doing this if I could though.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer as there doesn't seem to be a way to do what I want 'within the box'

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want

```
:set et
```

(short for expandtabs).  I *think* `vi` classic supports it.

Comment: I don't have a classic vi handy, but according to the vim help, it doesn't.

Comment: Oh wait, I do! FreeBSD has classic vi. It doesn't seem to have an expandtab option at all.

Comment: How unpleasant.  I guess it can't be done, then.  autoindent but not expandtabs... who woulda thunk it.

Comment: I was so hoping this would work, but alas :). If I could just get it not to convert spaces to tabs during autoindent, I'd be happy.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is well beyond the best-by date, but I just ran into this issue and was looking for an answer myself. A real pain when editing yaml on a FreeNAS box.

Anyhow, I successfully dealt with the issue by setting the value of tabstop to a large value.

':set tabstop=1000'